# How can I improve the query to make the ranking of players still correct even some of the players haven't play for a while?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to track the rank change of a player in the leaderboard according to the month and year. Due to that there are some players play no games in some certain time, their rank may be lower during that period.

The simplfied version of the table can be created:

```
create table rating 
(player_id Integer(20) ,
 game_id integer(20),
start_date_time date,
rating int (10) 
)

INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (1, 1,'2019-01-02',1250);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (1, 2,'2019-01-03',2230);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (1, 3,'2019-02-04',3362);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (1, 4,'2019-02-05',1578);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (2, 5,'2019-01-03',2269);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (2, 6,'2019-01-05',3641);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (2, 7,'2019-02-07',1548);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (2, 8,'2019-02-09',1100);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (3, 9,'2019-01-03',4690);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (3, 10,'2019-01-05',3258);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (3, 11,'2019-01-07',1520);
INSERT INTO rating (player_id, game_id,start_date_time,rating) VALUES (3, 12,'2019-01-09',3652);
```

The query I used is as followed:

```
select q1.rating_rank, q1.rating, q1.month,q1.year from (
SELECT player_id,month(start_date_time) as month, year(start_date_time) as year, round(avg(rating),2) as rating, count(*) as games_palyed,
rank() over(
partition by year(start_date_time),month(start_date_time)
order by  avg(rating) desc ) as rating_rank
FROM rating
group by player_id,month(start_date_time), year(start_date_time)
having rating is not null) as q1
where player_id=1
```

The result I got is:

```
rating_rank  rating    month  year 
3             1740.00    1    2019
1             2470.00    2    2019
```

But the third guy(id=3) is clearly better among them but because he didnt play for february, so the first guy can be ranked no.1. 
 In this situation i still want the third to be the 1 on the leaderboard. How should I fix this?

I am thinking maybe I can use a period which is 15 days before the date and 15 days after the date instead of the exact month. But I'm not sure how exactly can that to be done?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing as int(20). Luckily, the number in parentheses is almost entirely meaningless

Comment: Can you show us what the desired result would look like?

Answer (score 0):

It took time but i thing you can accomplish with this query:

First you have to generate all combinations between the possible datas and players:

This will give the dates:

```
WITH recursive mnths as (
    select  date_add(min(start_date_time),interval -DAY(min(start_date_time))+1 DAY) as mnth , 
    date_add(max(start_date_time),interval -DAY(max(start_date_time))+1 DAY) as maxmnth from rating 
      UNION ALL -- start date begining of next month
      SELECT DATE_ADD(mnth, INTERVAL +1 MONTH) , maxmnth
      FROM mnths WHERE 
      mnth < maxmnth
    )
```

An this will bind with all the players:

```
select * from mnths 
        cross join (Select distinct player_id from rating) as P
```

Then, besides the calculation involved you also need to get the rating value until the current period. This will be done by this subquery:

```
(
    SELECT 
        round(avg(rating),2) as rating
    from
    rating
    where start_date_time < mnths.mnth and player_id = P.player_id
    group by player_id,month(start_date_time), year(start_date_time)
    having round(avg(rating),2) is not null
    order by year(start_date_time) desc, month(start_date_time) desc 
    limit 1 ) as PrevRating,
```

That will allow you to rank using not only the current rank but the previous one when it does not exist.

```
order by  CASE WHEN AUX.rating IS NULL THEN case WHEN AUX.PrevRating IS NULL THEN
```

Binding all together you'll end up with this:

```
WITH recursive mnths as (
select  date_add(min(start_date_time),interval -DAY(min(start_date_time))+1 DAY) as mnth , 
date_add(max(start_date_time),interval -DAY(max(start_date_time))+1 DAY) as maxmnth from rating 
  UNION ALL -- start date begining of next month
  SELECT DATE_ADD(mnth, INTERVAL +1 MONTH) , maxmnth
  FROM mnths WHERE 
  mnth < maxmnth
)
select q1.rating_rank, q1.rating, q1.month,q1.year from (
select AUX.player_id, AUX.month, AUX.year, CASE WHEN AUX.rating IS NULL THEN case WHEN AUX.PrevRating IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE AUX.PrevRating END ELSE AUX.rating END as rating, 
AUX.games_palyed,
    rank() over(
    partition by AUX.month, AUX.year
    order by  CASE WHEN AUX.rating IS NULL THEN case WHEN AUX.PrevRating IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE AUX.PrevRating END ELSE AUX.rating END desc ) as rating_rank
FROM(
select 
    P.player_id, 
    MONTH(mnths.mnth) as month,
    YEAR(mnths.mnth) as year, 
    (
    SELECT 
        round(avg(rating),2) as rating
    from
    rating
    where start_date_time < mnths.mnth and player_id = P.player_id
    group by player_id,month(start_date_time), year(start_date_time)
    having round(avg(rating),2) is not null
    order by year(start_date_time) desc, month(start_date_time) desc 
    limit 1 ) as PrevRating,
    V.rating rating, 
    case when V.games_palyed IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE V.games_palyed END as games_palyed 
from mnths 
    cross join (Select distinct player_id from rating) as P
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        player_id, 
        month(start_date_time) as month, 
        year(start_date_time) as year, 
        round(avg(rating),2) as rating, 
        count(*) as games_palyed
    from
    rating as R 
    group by player_id,month(start_date_time), year(start_date_time)
    having rating is not null
    ) V On YEAR(mnths.mnth) = V.year and MONTH(mnths.mnth) = V.month and P.player_id = V.player_id
) as AUX
    ) as q1
where q1.player_id=1
```

You can se the result [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c9Z3eyHhXM4WHSf9Xux9eJ/0)